making a 5 minute Metroidvania prototype and wanna know if my dev process is good
I've been learning Godot and game dev as a whole since the start of this year and I've sunk dozens of hours into practicing making games in it, lately I've set out to make a very small sort of "test Metroidvania", I'm following a tutorial series on YouTube , and while the series isn't complete, it has everything I need, I've already implemented a lot of the stuff in the series, and I already have past experience with coding some basic features that aren't in the series.
Here is the scoping for my game, ✅ means I already implemented the feature, ️ means I've yet to code it and implement it.
My Scoping for this game:

Simple auto tile map with nice details ✅

Basic Player movement ✅

Player can Jump ✅

Player can attack with a sword and even use it while jumping and moving ✅

Player can double jump and even triple jump ✅

1 enemy type that can fly and chases the Player's position ✅

Player can collect power-up that allows them to double jump ✅

Player will be able to hit the enemy and kill it ️

Designing the level itself (it's gonna be pretty small lol) ️

Simple platforming challenges ️

Player will have to backtrack to the start once they obtain the double jump to reach the end area ️

a boss at the end that is just the flying enemy but bigger and has more health ️



Features that I wanna implement in future versions:

Player health and lose state ️

Spikes that damage the Player ️

A walking enemy ️

The same boss again but with enemies around it lol ️

More platforming challenges ️

Walljump ️

Keys and locked doors ️

Dash ️



I've been told to start small and always prototype, "the key is to always have a finished game at the start", I'm also trying to relatively stay in my current comfort zone with coding the features, I really don't wanna bite off more than I can chew and end up cancelling the game because I can't code essential features of it
So yeah that's my development, I'm confident I'm gonna be able to finish this game with my current skills, I just wanted to share my development and see if I can get any feedback, criticism is appreciated!


Good development process is a very subjective concept & the framing of your question is very broad. Whether or not your process is working for you & your situation is far more important than what other people think about it. If you have concerns about things that will or likely could keep you from your goals, editing to focus on those specifics would be more on topic. If you're looking for a more conversational discussion about process & your project, that's probably better suited to the Game Dev Stack Exchange chat.

I don't see what question exactly is being asked here. Please note that Stack Exchange is a Q&A community and not a discussion forum. Questions should actually ask a question. That question should be answerable in an objective manner. See What types of questions should I avoid asking? on the Help Center for more information.
